# How to ignore a specific sheet name?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

My code below, it is a combo box on a userform which allows the user to select certain data from other worksheets. My problem is, it also shows my 'Summary' sheet as a selectable option. How do I get it to show all worksheets in list index excluding the 'summary' worksheet?

```
Private Sub cmb_copycontact_Change()
If cmb_copycontact.ListIndex <> -1 Then

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cmb_copycontact.Value)
            txt_MailAdd1.Value = .Range("B21").Value
            txt_mailadd2.Value = .Range("B22").Value
            txt_mailburb.Value = .Range("B23").Value
            cmb_mailstate.Value = .Range("B24").Value
            txt_pcode.Value = .Range("B25").Value
            End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Modify the code, where you populate the combobox and just dont add it. The code you added does not help for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As UGP stated, exclude the Summary Sheet while populating the ComboBox on UserForm.

Incorporate the following code into your UserForm Initialize Event code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        Me.cmb_copycontact.AddItem ws.Name
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I am such an idiot ! I completely forgot about my Userform Initialize event. Been a long day, so sorry to waste your time but greatly appreciate the responses !

Comment: @JaysonD You're welcome. Glad your issue is resolved. :)